# How do you get CodePen to display the results?

Tags: html, css

I created a CodePen to compare it with jsfiddle. I added the html and the css. But...what now? How do I get it to show the results?

In jsfiddle you select "Run" and, when satisfied, "Update". But what's the trick in codePen? I'm sure it's "obvious," but I searched all over to no avail.

The white "presentation" page is visible at the bottom; PenSettings are set to "AutoSave" and "Auto Update Preview".

The same HTML and CSS renders fine at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/tL4s1hjr/114/)

Comment: The results should appear "instantly" (the default)? Is the preview window (white area at the bottom) visible?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought; it is visible, but nothing displays. PenSettings are set to "AutoSave" and "Auto Update Preview". The same exact HTML + CSS is rendered fine on jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/tL4s1hjr/114/)

Comment: I wonder if you have reached a code size limit? [This blog post](http://blog.codepen.io/documentation/editor/limitations/) mentions that with 5,000 - 10,000 lines of code "the editor [will] start to fail". You have 13,000+ lines in your HTML alone! (?) **EDIT:** I chopped your example down to about 5,000 lines and the preview appeared!

Comment: That's doubtless the problem (the sheer volume). CodePen is prettier, but jsfiddle can pump more iron.

Comment: Questions here are required to be about a [website under your control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results should appear "instantly" (by default) in the preview window at the bottom. By default, in "Pen Settings", the option "Auto Update Preview" is checked ("the preview will update automatically when you change code"). If this is unchecked then you get a "Run" button in the toolbar.

However, it appears that you have reached a limitation of CodePen! [This blog post discusses file size limitations](http://blog.codepen.io/documentation/editor/limitations/) and states that:

> One of the limitations of the CodePen editor is sheer volume of code. ... when they start hitting 5,000 - 10,000 or more lines of code, you'll see the editor start to fail.

In your example, you had 13,000+ lines of HTML and indeed it failed to "Preview", even with the "Auto Update Preview" option unchecked and hitting "Run" manually. However, chopping the code down to about 5,000 lines produced a result. (It would have been useful to have had some kind of advisory/warning, since "nothing" is not particularly helpful!)